# Writing a list to a file using Pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I'm relatively new to Python, and I have a Shakespeare poem as a list that I want to write into a folder on my computer and save, but be able to open it again later on.

get_text(page_1) = [Over hill, over dale, Thorough bush, thorough brier, Over park, over pale, Thorough flood, thorough fire! I do wander everywhere, Swifter than the moon's sphere; And I serve the Fairy Queen, To dew her orbs upon the green; The cowslips tall her pensioners be; In their gold coats spots you see; Those be rubies, fairy favours; In those freckles live their savours; I must go seek some dewdrops here, And hang a pearl in every cowslip's ear.]

Here's what I have:

```
import pickle 

pickle.dump(get_text(page_1),'C:\Users\Matt\Honors Poems')
```

How should I fix this so that it'll be able to write into a file on my computer?

Comment: You could find the answer just by reading the first lines of the Pickle documentation...

Answer (score 2):

The second argument has to be an open file object:

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Matt\Honors Poems', 'wb') as outfile:
    pickle.dump(get_text(page_1), outfile)
```

Comment: Getting an IOError: [Errno 13] saying that my permission is denied. Any suggestions? Thank you in advance, by the way.

Comment: It's there - I copied the address at text and there's nothing in the folder.

Comment: Can you create *any* files in that folder from Python? Does using another folder work?